# Element UI: Emitting an event on sort caret click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

Is there any way to emit an event (preferably with the same parameters as header-click) when sorting carets are clicked on a [table](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) with sortable columns?

I can emit an event by clicking on the header of any sortable column (header-click), but nothing happens when clicking on the sort carets.

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 2):

> I can emit an event by clicking on the header of any sortable column
>   (header-click), but nothing happens when clicking on the sort carets.

this is the expected behavior, it seems you are after `sort-change` event which is getting triggered when table's sorting changes:

```
<template>
  <el-table @sort-change="sortChange" @header-click="headerClick" :data="tableData" :default-sort="{prop: 'date', order: 'descending'}" style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" sortable width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" sortable width="180">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address" sortable :formatter="formatter">
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>



<script>
export default {
 data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          date: '2016-05-03',
          name: 'Tom',
          address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
        },
        //...
       ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      sortChange(sortProps){
          this.headerClick(sortProps.column,event) //optional: trigger header-click event
      },
      headerClick(column, event){
        console.log("Header clicked: " + JSON.stringify(column))
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/nucjgxdq/)

Comment: Thanks. My situation is a little unique in that I wanted to do some processing to the data between the header/caret being clicked and the sort happening, which unfortunately means sort-change isn't really useful to me.

I wound up just using JS + Vue to sort rather than Element UI.